# Float icon inside button to the right

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm positioning an icon inside a button. To align the icon to the right of the button, I'm using `float: right` on the icon. But as you'll see, this causes the icon to overflow on Firefox, so I need another solution.

### Things to note

1. I want the text in the button to be centrally aligned, so adding `float: left` to the text isn't an option
2. The icon needs to be floated to the right of the button

Here's the `Sass` for the icon and button:

```
.icon-icomoon
    font-family: 'icomoon' !important
    speak: none
    font-style: normal
    font-weight: normal
    font-variant: normal
    text-transform: none
    line-height: 1
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale

.icon-arrow-right:before
    content: "\e910"

.btn
    border-radius: 0
    padding: 20px 40px
    font-weight: 600
    font-family: $fontSansSerif
    font-size: 1.9em

    span.icon-arrow-right
        float: right
        font-size: 40px

.mobile-and-tablet-only
    display: none

    @media screen and (max-width: $mediaBreakpointTablet)
        display: block

.desktop-only
    display: none

    @media screen and (min-width: $mediaBreakpointTablet+1)
        display: block
```

Here's the `HTML` for the button:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-success">
  <span class="desktop-only">
    Let's make something awesome together
    <span class="icon-icomoon icon-arrow-right"></span>
  </span>
  <span class="mobile-and-tablet-only">
    Let's work together
    <span class="icon-icomoon icon-arrow-right"></span>
  </span>
</a>
```

Here's what it looks like in the browser on Chrome:

[image: What the button looks like on Chrome]

And here's what it looks like on Firefox. As you can see, the width of the text is at 100% which is causing the icon to overflow:

[image: Button on Firefox]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving the `a.btn` `position:relative` and then positioning the `span.icon-arrow-right` absolutely (`position: absolute`). Then you can give the arrow icon any desired position by adding `right: 3%; top: 33%` to it.

Comment: The icon needs to be floated exactly to the right of the button, so adding `right` to it won't work

Comment: @mightyspaj why not? I just did a little test in codepen, while not replicating the exact structure, it seemed to work.

Comment: Ahh, yes I see what you mean, my mistake. I've just re-tested it and it works. Before I was using `right` incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

You can try to make the spans inside the button inline blocks (to prevent spanning 100% of the button width). Also don't forget to use clearfix to the parent container (`.btn`) of the floated span.

```
.btn {
  text-align: center;
  @include clearfix();

  > span {
    display: inline-block;

    &.icon-icomoon {
      float: right;
    }
  }
}

@mixin clearfix() {
  &::after {
    display: block;
    content: "";
    clear: both;
  }
}
```

Comment: @mightyspaj, though this is a Bootstrap code, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `:after` on your span

```
btn {
   position:relative;
}
span{
  text-align:center;
}
span:after {
       content: url(myicon.png);

}
```

As this way, you didn't need this

```
<span class="icon-icomoon icon-arrow-right"></span>
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/4fgvrsjL/5/)
[example 2](https://jsfiddle.net/4fgvrsjL/2/)

OR you can use display: inline-block by giving them width in %. Also you can use [display:flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/Disposition_des_bo%C3%AEtes_flexibles_CSS/Utilisation_des_flexbox_en_CSS).

Comment: Using `:after` produces the same issue as `:before`

Comment: I also tried using `display: inline-flex`. It doesn't allow you to float the icon to the right (which is what I want). As for using `display: inline-block`, I want to avoid providing manual `%` widths (it's messy)

Comment: it's work click on my example on firefox and chrome : you need use position : absolute on your after : and a position relative on his parent .btn as a do in my example above on fiddle.     
span:after {
         content: "★";
         position: absolute;
          right: 150px;
    }

Answer (score 0):

Like this.

```css
span{
  font-size:16px
}

img{
  vertical-align:-15%;
}
```

```html
<button>
  <span>My Text</span>
  <img src="https://rack.pub/media/bitcoin.png" height="16px" >
</button>
```

Comment: This doesn't float the icon to the right of the button, though

Comment: You want the icon to lie outside of the button, to the right of the button?